# Converting from Java to VBA

Tags: java, vba, ms-access

I need a to create a VBA function that extract a text from a string
I wrote this java method

```
public static String extract(String str) {

    String s = str.substring(str.indexOf("'"),str.lastIndexOf("'"));
    String fg = s.substring(s.indexOf("'")+1, s.indexOf("to")-2);
    String sg = s.substring(s.indexOf("to")+4);

    return sg;

}
```

which do what I want but in VBA I can't find equivalent to indexOf and lastIndexOf
And most importantly how to mimic java substring using indexes of characters without using length to extract as in VBA. 
could anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: SO isn't a body-shop. Try to do it yourself; if you get stuck, come back and ask questions.

Answer (score 6):

```
idx = str.indexOf("'");

// is equivalent of

idx = InStr(str, "'")
```

and

```
idx = str.lastIndexOf("'");

// is equivalent of

idx = InStrRev(str, "'")
```

and

```
str = str.substring(start, end)

// is equivalent of

str = Mid(str, start, end - start)
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent methods to indexOf and lastIndexOf are inStr and inStrRev.

See http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php for example.

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent for "substring" is "mid" function.